# In java what is the purpose of NonWildcardTypeArguments following the new keyword?

Tags: java, parsing, syntax

I was looking through the [java language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) and saw this way of writing a creator:

```
Creator:  
NonWildcardTypeArguments CreatedName ClassCreatorRest
```

In plain code:

```java
new <Integer> String("1");
// or
new <String,Integer> Integer(5);
//or
new <Constructor,String,Integer> ArrayList<String>(5);
```

In every example I can think of the class list is not useful as far as I can tell. Can you please give me an example when the typelist after the new keyword serves a purpose.

Comment: Generic exists for type safety. Legacy code might have a generic-like constructor, which is taking a parameter as `Object`. After generic was introduced, we could replace `Box(Object o){}` with `<T> Box(T o){}`, providing backward compatibility too. Generic doesn't exist for just collection only. By the way, if the constructor doesn't take a parameter, how do you know the type parameter will be? — Type inference doesn't happen. In this case, you have to explicitly specify the type argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is invalid unless you run into the **extremely exotic** java syntactical constructor of a type-varred constructor. Essentially, you should never be doing this. It's there for language completeness and probably should never have been added to java.

You can put type param definitions on classes, this is the most common mode. For example, `ArrayList` has a type variable; it is declared as follows:

```
class ArrayList<E> implements List<E> { ... }
```

The first `<E>` declares that there is some type `E` with no bounds. It is then used immediately (the first `<E>` and the second `<E>` look identical, but one declares the type var, the other is a type var usage, and thus these are quite different. So far so good.

But you can also declare them directly on a method. For example:

```
public static <E> coalesce(E... items) {
  for (E item : items) if (item != null) return item;
  return item;
}
```

This method can be invoked with as many object refs as you please and will return the first one that isn't `null`, and the invocation's type will be the common denominator amongst all the parameters. In other words, this would compile:

```
String x = coalesce(null, someString, "defaultValue");
```

Whereas if we had written it:

```
public static Object coalesce(Object... items) {
  for (Object item : items) if (item != null) return item;
  return item;
}
```

Then, whilst `coalesce(null, someStringRef, "default")` would obviously neccessarily return a `String`, the compiler doesn't know that and thus `String x = coalesce(..)` would NOT compile. You'd have to inject a cast. The point of generics is to not have to do that.

### And now to the answer to your question

This same feature (on-method type params) is available on constructors:

```
public class Example<T> {
  public <A> Example(A first, A second) {
  }
}
```

is legal java. It is extremely difficult to attempt to think of a situation where you'd want on-constructor generics. Constructors have no return type, and the whole point is that the typeparam is needed just for the constructor and ceases all relevance once you're done with it (if it is relevant to the instance itself, you'd put it on the type, just like `<E>` in the example above). Hence why you see it effectively never in java code. Nevertheless, if you were to write it, *and* you don't want `javac` to infer the generics but instead want to be explicit about it, the syntax you are reading about is how you'd do it:

```
new <String>Example<Integer>("a", "b");
```

Would invoke that constructor and force `A` to be `String` and `T` to be `Integer`.

There are boatloads of weird and confusing constructs in the JLS that nobody ever uses. Hence it's not generally a good idea to just read through the JLS, you'll learn something but it is a highly inefficient way of learning things.

Comment: I went ahead and edited a couple small things on your answer but thanks so much for the quick and comprehensive reply!
I see now that I do not have permission to make edits. There were just a couple places where the type references were wrong but was clear what they should be.